# Inserting missing range of values in json data

Tags: mysql, json

I am querying a mysql database to return the number of times a certain pain score has been entered by a user. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    User,
    CAST(Value as UNSIGNED)as Pain_Score, 
    COUNT(Value) as Pain_Score_Count
FROM
    pain_score
WHERE
    Text = 'Pain Score'
AND
    User = :user
GROUP BY 
    Value
ORDER BY
    Pain_Score
ASC
```

Table schema:

```
Field   Type
id      int(10)
Text    varchar(250)
User    varchar(255)
Value   varchar(15000)
```

The query is returning data in json format that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "User": "Test, User",
        "Pain_Score": "0",
        "Pain_Score_Count": "6"
    },
    {
        "User": "Test, User",
        "Pain_Score": "5",
        "Pain_Score_Count": "4"
    },
    {
        "User": "Test, User",
        "Pain_Score": "6",
        "Pain_Score_Count": "3"
    },
    {
        "User": "Test, User",
        "Pain_Score": "7",
        "Pain_Score_Count": "1"
    },
    {
        "User": "Test, User",
        "Pain_Score": "8",
        "Pain_Score_Count": "4"
    }
]
```

But for any given set of data returned I need a Pain_Score range from 0 to 10, ie:

```
[
        {
            "User": "Test, User",
            "Pain_Score": "0",
            "Pain_Score_Count": "6"
        },
        {
            "User": "Test, User",
            "Pain_Score": "1",
            "Pain_Score_Count": "0"
        },
        {
            "User": "Test, User",
            "Pain_Score": "2",
            "Pain_Score_Count": "0"
        },
        {
            "User": "Test, User",
            "Pain_Score": "3",
            "Pain_Score_Count": "0"
        },
        {
            "User": "Test, User",
            "Pain_Score": "4",
            "Pain_Score_Count": "0"
        },
        {
            "User": "Test, User",
            "Pain_Score": "5",
            "Pain_Score_Count": "4"
        },
        {
            "User": "Test, User",
            "Pain_Score": "6",
            "Pain_Score_Count": "3"
        },
        {
            "User": "Test, User",
            "Pain_Score": "7",
            "Pain_Score_Count": "1"
        },
        {
            "User": "Test, User",
            "Pain_Score": "8",
            "Pain_Score_Count": "4"
        },
        {
            "User": "Test, User",
            "Pain_Score": "9",
            "Pain_Score_Count": "0"
        },
        {
            "User": "Test, User",
            "Pain_Score": "10",
            "Pain_Score_Count": "0"
        }
    ]
```

Is there a way to return the missing range of Pain_Score values by editing the query or is there a simple way to insert the missing values for a random set of given Pain_Score values?

Comment: Why is this tagged JS/jQuery? Are you looking to handle this client side by filling in the missing values?

Comment: Can you provide your table schema please?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am looking for preferably a query solution, just posting the output data for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to synthesize all the numbers you're wanting to include and join on that. Here's one way to do it. [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fhwZfrUEEjQYoafKYXQS45/1)

```
SELECT
    User,
    num as Pain_Score,
    COUNT(Value) as Pain_Score_Count
FROM
    pain_score
RIGHT JOIN (select 0 num union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) nums
    ON num = Value
    AND User = "Test, User"
    AND Text = "Pain Score"
GROUP BY 
    num, User
ORDER BY num ASC
```

In this example, I've hardcoded the user, but you should be able to adjust the `SELECT` and `JOIN` statements to replace `User` and `"Test, User"` with your `:User` variable, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, synthesizing the necessary values is definitely the most painless way